# Is it possible to set kartik-gridview editable to inline instead of popup?

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have built the following GridView:

```
use yii\helpers\Html;
use kartik\grid\GridView;
use kartik\editable\Editable;

<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider'=> $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        'string_identifier', 
        [
            'class' => 'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
            'attribute' => 'text',
            'pageSummary' => true,
            'readonly' => false,
            'content' => function($data){return '<div class="text_content">'.htmlentities($data->text).'</div>';},
            'editableOptions' => [
                'header' => 'Text',
                'inputType' => \kartik\editable\Editable::INPUT_TEXT,
                'options' => [
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'asPopover' => false,
                    ]
                ]
            ],
        ], 
        [
            'attribute' => 'language_id',
            'filter' => Language::getFilter(),
            'content' => function($data){return $data->language->title;},
        ],
    ],
    'responsive'=>true,
    'hover'=>true,
    'export' => false,
]) ?>
```

But the editable column is always a popup. I want to set it to inline as mentioned in the documention of Editable ([link](http://demos.krajee.com/editable#usage-inline)).

I tried to set `asPopover => false` inside `pluginOptions` and also inside `options` but nothing changed.

I'm happy about any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you inserted this in wrong section. Try this instead:

```
'editableOptions' => [                
    'asPopover' => false,
],
```

From the [EditableColumn](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-grid/blob/master/EditableColumn.php) docs for `editableOptions`:

> @var array|Closure the configuration options for the
>   [[\kartik\editable\Editable]] widget.

And this property exists in [Editable widget](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-editable/blob/master/Editable.php).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this before but then I get this error: Setting unknown property: kartik\editable\Editable::asPopover

Comment: Check that you have the latest version. As you can see this property exists [here](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-editable/blob/master/Editable.php#L129).

Comment: Yes, thanks. I had changed minimum-stability to stable, this was my fault :( thanks for your help!